# Getting Firebase Permission Denied with correct rules(I guess)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am making an Android application. After I set the rules, when I try to access data on this specific children, I get the message Listen at / failed.

My code is as follow :

```
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
String useruid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
childUpdates.put("/groups/" + upperString + "/owner/", useruid);
childUpdates.put("/groups" + upperString + "/members/" + useruid, Settings.mName);
childUpdates.put("/groups" + upperString + "/name/", upperString);
childUpdates.put("/users/" + useruid + "/group/", upperString);
final DatabaseReference mDatGroups = mDatabase.child("/");
mDatGroups.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

And then my rules:

```
"groups": {
  ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').exists() == false",
   "$objectType": {
    "members": {
      ".validate": "
        auth != null && 
        newData.val() == auth.uid && 
        newData.parent().parent().parent().child('group-invites').child(auth.uid).child($objectType).exists() != null && 
        newData.parent().parent().parent().child('groups').child($objectType).child('members-invited').child(auth.uid).exists() != null
      ",
      ".read": "root.child('groups').child($objectType).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists() != null",
      ".write": "auth != null && root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').exists() == false"
    },
    "name": {
      ".read": "root.child('groups').child($objectType).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists() != null",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').exists() == false"
    },
    "owner": {
      ".read": "root.child('groups').child($objectType).child('members').child(auth.uid).exists() != null",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('group').exists() == false"
    }
  }

}
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
  }
}
```

I get Permission denied when i try to updateChildren, so my question is what is causing that permission deny since I can write on that in Firebase Rules Simulator.

---------------------------------------//----------------------------------
PROBLEM SOLVED. members rules were wrong.

Comment: What's `upperString`?

Comment: UpperString is the name of the group. I just called it UpperString because basicaly it is just capitalizing the first letter.

Comment: Can you include the minimum JSON (as text, no screenshot) that is in the database when you run the code?

Comment: Are you authenticated correctly? This can be an issue if it works in the simulator but not in your app.

Comment: I'll debug that. But since I can get the uid from mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid() I think that isn't a problem. Currently I'm not at home so I can't post json.